# Why can't I initialize state in client component via prop sent from server component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm reading the value off a cookie inside a server component and then passing that value to a child client component. When I do so, the `user` prop is successfully rendered and logged as the user object  `{id: 1, name: "John Doe"}`, but the client component's `authUser` state variable is just `{ token: "" }`. This makes no sense to me, especially given the value is being logged as an object in the browser console, but then setting the state to a different variable, without the original object having mutated.

If I refresh the page everything works as I expect. I've tried all of the cache invalidation strategies I could find in the next docs, but am still coming up short. What am I missing here? Also strange is that changing it from `useState` to `useMemo` with `const authUser = useMemo(() => user, [user]);` seems to capture the user object as I'd expect.

```
// server component

import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

import { Inner } from "@/components/inner";

export const Outer = async () => {
  const token = (await cookies().get("jwt")?.value) || "";

  let user: any = {
    token,
  };

  try {
    user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET as string);
  } catch {}


  return <Inner user={user} />;
};
```

```
// client component

"use client";

export const Inner = ({ user }: { user?: any }) => {
  console.log(user); // this always accurately logs the actual user object

  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = React.useState(user);

  return (
    <pre className="text-green-200">
      {JSON.stringify({ user, authUser })}
    </pre>
  );
};
```